# How to split a user inputted list of 8 numbers into quarters

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

Currently, I have
`data = input('Please input 8 numbers \n')`
What I want to do is split this list into quarters so I may input them into matrices A and B of a 2x2 format

Comment: Please, how does this realate to numpy? Could you show a desired `input`/`output` pair?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, for that, you can do

```
data = input('Please input 8 numbers \n')
quarters = []
split_input = data.split(" ")
for i in range(0, len(split_input), 2):
    quarters.append([split_input[i], split_input[i+1]])

print(quarters)
```

```
Please input 8 numbers 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the order in which the input should be stored in A, B:

```py
import numpy as np

split_input = input('Please input 8 numbers \n').split(" ")
A, B = np.array(split_input, dtype='float').reshape(2, 2, 2)

print(A)
print(B)
```

```sh
Please input 8 numbers 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
[[1. 2.]
 [3. 4.]]
[[5. 6.]
 [7. 8.]]
```

or

```py
arr = np.array(split_input, dtype='float').reshape(2, 2, 2)
A, B = np.swapaxes(arr, 0, 1)

print(A)
print(B)
```

```
[[1. 2.]
 [5. 6.]]
[[3. 4.]
 [7. 8.]]
```

or

```py
arr = np.array(split_input, dtype='float').reshape(2, 2, 2)
A, B = np.swapaxes(arr, 1, 2)

print(A)
print(B)
```

```
[[1. 3.]
 [2. 4.]]
[[5. 7.]
 [6. 8.]]
```

etc.

Comment: Thats a lot of effort master Luc, I say you deserve an upvote too.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not, how this site should work . I would rather get a stricter problem description.

Answer (score 0):

separated with **,**

```
import numpy as np

_input = input('Please input 8 numbers \n')
int_input = [int(x) for x in _input.split(',')]
x = np.array(int_input).reshape(2, 2, 2)
```